# Reloading div containing PHP script every minute

Tags: php, jquery, scheduled-tasks, reload

My page has a div where the content is written by a PHP script.

```
 <div id="feastsaint"> <!-- Feast or Saint of the day -->
     <?php 

        if(isset($_COOKIE["datetoday"])) {
           echo $_COOKIE["datetoday"];
        }

        if(isset($_COOKIE["month"]) and isset($_COOKIE["day"]) and isset($_COOKIE["year"])) { 
          $showfeast = file_get_contents('http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$_COOKIE["year"].$_COOKIE["month"].$_COOKIE["day"].'&type=feast&lang=AM');
          $showliturt = file_get_contents('http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$_COOKIE["year"].$_COOKIE["month"].$_COOKIE["day"].'&type=liturgic_t&lang=AM');
          $showsaints = file_get_contents('http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$_COOKIE["year"].$_COOKIE["month"].$_COOKIE["day"].'&type=saint&lang=AM');
          if ( !empty($showfeast) ) {
            echo ' - '.$showfeast;
          }
          else if ( !empty($showliturt) ) {

            $stlit = strpos($showliturt, 'of the');
            if ( $stlit ) {
               $trunclitur = substr($showliturt, $stlit+7);
               echo ' - '.$trunclitur;
            }
            else {
              $stlits = strpos($showliturt, 'aint');
              if ( $stlits ) {
                ;
              }
              else {
               echo ' - '.$showliturt;

              }

            }

          }
          if ( !empty($showsaints) ) {
            echo ' - '.$showsaints;
          }
        } 

        $widfeast = strlen($showfeast);

        $widlitur = strlen($trunclitur);

        $widsaint = strlen($showsaints);

        $widtha = $widfeast + $widsaint;

        $widthb = $widlitur + $widsaint;

        if ($widtha > 240 || $widthb > 240) {
          echo '<span>'.$showsaints.'</span>';
        }

     ?>
 </div> <!-- End Feast or Saint of the day -->
```

How do I tell the HTML page to reload this div after midnight of the current date?  The problem is that the information shown is outdated the first few times I open the page the next day.  Then it has the current information.  I store the date in cookies, then with the date I get the other information.  If I make the cookies expire too quickly, then I end up with no information at all.  So I want to try to refresh the div automatically.

How do I make a jquery call to reload the div every few hours, with the PHP script shown?

Comment: The PHP script is irrelavant. What you want to happen is on the client, not the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP code is actually not relevant. The jQuery `load()` function will load the resulting HTML from any PHP page into a specified div

http://api.jquery.com/load/

This code will re-load the content into the div every 3,600,000 milliseconds (or every hour)

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('#divId').load('theContent.php');
}, 3600000);
```

Comment: agreed, but how does this help the OP schedule the load?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the number of milliseconds until midnight.

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
     $('#myDiv').load('someScript.php');
},milliseconds)
```

Comment: the OP asked `How do I make a jquery call to reload the div every few hours` - While your solution is probably better, it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: OK, looks like setinterval is the way to request a reload.  I added to my code and will update on whether this fixes the problem.